# Visible satellite imagery, atmospheric anomaly (descending air) in cumulus fields?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, remote-sensing, weather-satellites, mesoscale-meteorology

When looking at GOES satellite imagery, in the visible channels. I have noticed these "lines" if you will, usually forms in Cumulus fields. I understand the process of the 'Mackerel sky' (Herringbone Clouds) and how capping creates the appearance of the lines of cumulus etc... But, there seems to sometimes be a stationary line of descending air that causes the clouds to 'dissipate' / disappear and then re-appear on the other side. Is this an imagery anomaly due to the stretching of the picture at higher latitudes? or Atmospheric Gravity waves? Any idea's?

Here are some screenshots with red lines marking the area's I'm talking about and there are links to full video's below. You will probably have to watch the video's to get a good idea of what I'm talking about.

[image: GOES Visible Imagery]

VIDEO [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hePhBvXkllpepRjx7ceU_v_NZJWWm1NY/view?usp=sharing)

[image: GOES Visible]

VIDEO [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i7lSZ68H_imbcW5J3bB-TTtf-2RP-XQy/view?usp=sharing)

This one might be the same process, but I'm not sure?

[image: GOES Satellite]

VIDEO [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hebo0eKUHuYg3vQ4KWVRu75yLrZ3U0kq/view?usp=sharing)